# How to display something in a root view in ios using storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating an application in ios using storyboard. I have a Tab Bar Controller as my root view, from this page I can navigate to other pages using the tabs, but how can I insert any text or image in the root view for the tab bar controller.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by '_root page_'?

Comment: Main controller (with tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default page (or root page as you are putting it) for a tab bar controller *is* one of the other `UIViewController`s only. A `UITabBarController` can show another `UIViewController` inside it. There can be no text or image right inside a `UITabBarController`, but there can be  a `UIViewController` inside it which has text or images. It is just a container for other view controllers.

Check out this [example](http://simplecode.me/2011/12/05/tab-based-ios-apps-uitabbarcontroller/), it will help simplify things.

```
FirstViewController *fistView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

NSArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fistView, secondView, nil];
self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabController setViewControllers:viewControllersArray animated:YES];
```

In the code above, the `firstView` controller will be displayed initially in the `tabController`, so what you want to do is add text and images and stuff inside `firstView`'s xib file (or code).

Comment: I am using storyboard.

Comment: You should add the text and labels in the first view controller that the UITabBarController is showing.

Comment: Actually I was thinking deeply towards technical aspects,thank u a lot, I got it @aksh1t